# Uploading a spreadsheet for ease of reference

Tags: discussion

How do I upload my spreadsheet in a question so I can reference what I am trying to do with all the formulas currently working as it is 85% formulas

Comment: Do you have any cloud storage service, like OneDrive? If yes,  you may upload the spreadsheet first, then share it with us.

Comment: and please use only ad-free services like OneDrive, Dropbox, etc. not some obscure site that is plastered with ads. Before doing that, try to describe the issue. In many cases you don't need a full workbook to illustrate. Just a small data sample will hit the sweet spot in many cases and can often be posted as text in the question.

Comment: THANK YOU. I will either use Google Drive or Dropbox didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [please don’t post images of spreadsheets (or other text).](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)

If you need to be able to upload the spreadsheet to explain the question, that’s a sign that you haven’t thought about your question enough to be ready to ask it on Super User.  First of all, some people simply will refuse to download files out of concern about malware.  Secondly, if you present more than about 50 cells (e.g., 5 columns × 10 rows) of sample data, some people won’t bother looking at it, thinking that you are substituting quantity of data for quality of information (i.e., narrative/explanation) and/or that you have a problem that’s so big and complex that it really should be further analyzed (by you) and decomposed into smaller, more manageable pieces (which you should perhaps then ask as multiple separate questions).

When you have narrowed the scope of your question, create a *small* data set that illustrates your problem (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).  It doesn’t have to be your *real* data; it’s OK (and preferable) to use dummy/test data.  Don’t use 10-digit numbers and 20-letter Welsh words if you can make do with 2-digit numbers and short words like “red” and “orange”.  And then post a textual representation of your data set, as was done [here](https://superuser.com/q/1289084/150988), [here](https://superuser.com/q/889201/150988), [here](https://superuser.com/q/443967/150988), [here](https://superuser.com/q/684851/150988), [here](https://superuser.com/q/815333/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table) or the [Plain Text Tables generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) site if you want.

In your question, be sure to include the output data you expect from your input data (clearly identifying which is which) and give a clear description of the computation you want Excel to do.

Comment: I appreciate your comments however, my question was clear and in the user info it was recommended that I a picture be supplied to help clarify the question but the question should stand alone which it does. I get that I am not as smart as most people answering questions and that you are only trying to assist but you have now made me feel like a complete dick and I will no longer post questions in fear of being humiliated because I did what was recommended.